# how to hashmap values in jsonrest script

Tags: java, json, dojo

Hi I'm making a Maven rest web service application in this I need to get the hashmap values in my JSONRest code. How can I do this?

Here is my service code which prints the JSON values:

```
@GET
@Path("/ind")
@Produces("application/json")
public HashMap<String,String> json()
{
    HashMap<String,String> m = new HashMap<String,String>();

    m.put("Fiyas", "basha");
    m.put("Rajesh", "Babu");

    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();

    try {
        if(j != null)
        j.put("emp", m);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }

    return m;
}
```

Which prints `{"Fiyas":"basha","Rajesh":"Babu"}`

Now I need to call this JSON values in the select box on the particular JSON emp key in my dojo script

my JSONRest code:

```
 <script>
    require(["dojo/store/JsonRest", "dojo/dom-construct"], function(JsonRest, domConst){
        var store = new JsonRest({
            target: "http://localhost:8080/userservices/rest/rest/ind",
        });

        store.query().then(function(jsonData){
            alert(jsonData.emp);
            domConst.place("<option value=''>Year's of Exp</option>","Experience");
            for(var i in jsonData.emp)
            {
                domConst.place("<option value="+jsonData.emp[i]+">" + jsonData.emp[i] +  "</option>","Experience");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm getting `undefined` and can't get the values in this script, But I'm getting a response and JSON values in firebug.

How do I get the hashmap values one by one? Please, any help will be appreciated, and suggest to me what I'm doing wrong.

Please Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're bouncing off a Java servlet, you need to pass the JSON string back to the front-end as a response. I don't know what your structure is, but if your servlet extends `HttpServlet`, you should do something of this ilk:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
    HashMap<String, String> m = json();
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();

    try {
        if(j != null) {
            j.put("emp", m);
        }
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }

    // Send the JSON string back
    response.getWriter().print(j.toString());
}
```

And your `json()` method can be trimmed down a bit:

```
@GET
@Path("/ind")
@Produces("application/json")
public HashMap<String,String> json()
{
    HashMap<String,String> m = new HashMap<String,String>();

    m.put("Fiyas", "basha");
    m.put("Rajesh", "Babu");

    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response for a `store.query` call is supposed to be an array of hash maps, not a single object. `store.get` is what returns a single object. Responses to `store.query` also need to have a Content-Range header to describe how many total objects are available on the server. This is all documented in the [Implementing a REST server](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#implementing-a-rest-server) documentation for the JsonRest store.